# BroadcastReceiver's onReceive method is not getting called

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am trying to invoke certain function in my app at specific time every week. Here is what I did:

In my activity I have following code

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

PendingIntent pIntent;

//my function to get first invoke time
        long lAlarmStartTime = getAlarmStartTime(Calendar.SUNDAY, alrm);

Intent intentArg = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RcvAlarms.class).putExtra    (ALARM_ALARM_ID,  alrm.getMy_id());

pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
                (int) task.getMy_id() * 10 + Calendar.SUNDAY,
                intentArg, flag);

am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, lAlarmStartTime,
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pIntent);
```

---

I have another another class:

```
public class RcvAlarms extends BroadcastReceiver {

public RcvAlarms() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {//my job }
```

---

My manifest has the following receiver tag inside the application tag:

```
<receiver android:name=".RcvAlarms" android.text="Repeat Task Receiver"></receiver>
```

Could someone please tell me why `onReceive` is not getting invoked when my device time reaches start time?

Answer (score 0):

The code when you set the alarm is the code you'd use to have it launch an activity.  I think you need PendingIntent.getBroadcast(), not PendingIntent.getActivity().

Comment: can you help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39901321/is-it-possible-to-call-onreceive-method-from-a-dialog