# Is it possible to call onReceive method from a dialog?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-broadcastreceiver

I have a **custom dialog** with `editText` and `save button`. When `button` clicked, I want it call **MyReceiver**. But the log and Toast in **MyReceiver** never get displayed.

**Reminder**

```
  final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
                View promptView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_with_edittext, null);
                Button save = (Button) promptView.findViewById(R.id.okBtn);
                final EditText task = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.task);
                time = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.time);
                date = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.date);
                final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                date.setOnClickListener(this);

                save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String addTask= task.getText().toString();
                        String time1= time.getText().toString();
                        String date1= date.getText().toString();
                        if (adapter != null) {
                            adapter.add(addTask,time1,date1);
                            insertTask(addTask, time1, date1);
                            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                            alert.dismiss();
                            check();
                        }
                        c.set(Calendar.YEAR,year1);
                        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month1);
                        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day1);
                        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour1);
                        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min1);
                        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                        c.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.AM);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),year1+""+month1+""+day1+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),hour1+""+min1+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(ReminderPage.this, MyReceiver.class);
                        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ReminderPage.this, 123456789, myIntent,0);
                        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Alarm",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                });
                alert.setView(promptView);
                alert.show();
                return true;
```

**MyReceiver**

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.i("App", "called receiver method");
        try{
            Toast.makeText(context,"Call Utils1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Utils1.generateNotification(context);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(context,"Not Call Utils1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I also added this in my AndroidMainfest

```
 <receiver android:name="com.example.MyReceiver"></receiver>
```

**Utils1**

```
public class Utils1 {

        public static NotificationManager mManager;

        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        public static void generateNotification(Context context){
            mManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context,Register.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, intent1, 0);
            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
            builder.setAutoCancel(false);
            builder.setTicker("this is ticker text");
            builder.setContentTitle("WhatsApp Notification");
            builder.setContentText("You have a new message");
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.done);
            builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            builder.setOngoing(true);
            builder.setSubText("This is subtext...");   //API level 16
            builder.setNumber(100);
            builder.build();

            Notification myNotication = builder.getNotification();
            mManager.notify(0, myNotication);
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is possible but you need to make a custom Dialog.

Comment: When you click the button, you are creating an alarm. When that alarm goes off, your `BroadcastReceiver` will be called. Have you checked that the time you are setting the alarm for is correct? Please add some logging to your code and check that `c.getTimeInMillis()` actually contains the value that you think it should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your question, the following steps will give you exactly what you want.

**1.)** In your *AndroidManifest.xml* replace your `receiver`

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.MyReceiver"></receiver>
```

by the following:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" />
```

**2.)** Finally add this in your code for the button listener:

```
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // ...
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(
                new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyReceiver.class));
        // ...
    }
});
```

That's it, now run your app. Whenever you click your `save` button, you will notice that the `onReceive()` method in your class `MyReceiver` will get called properly. That means your logcat output will be

```
I/App: called receiver method
```

as expected and your `Toast` message `Call Utils1` will also be displayed correctly.

Comment: I use your code and it works. But do you have any idea why the notifications always show without following the time set ?

Comment: push notifications

Comment: The question stated in your title has already been answered and you can accept my answer when it solved this problem. Please open a new question about your notification issue and provide enough detail. It makes no sense to discuss a new question or problem here in the comments section.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but you need to make a custom Dialog. Custom like a new Class that extends DialogFragment. There you create a instance of you receiver and register for it like this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
 super.onResume();
 getActivity.registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
 if(mReceiver != null) {
   getActivity.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
   mReceiver = null;
   }
 super.onPause();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sending a class-based intent to a broadcast receiver doesn't work.  Intents with a class in them are for launching activities, not broadcast messages.

To send a message to a broadcast receiver, you need to use an intent with an action string, and register the string with an intent filter in your manifest.

Comment: can you provide some example ?

Comment: There are lots of examples in the documentation for BroadcastReceiver; I'd suggest having a look at those.

Answer (score 1):

If you've already got the data.You can just use it like this:

```
MyReceiver receiver = new MyReceiver();
receiver.onReceive(context,intent);
```

Call `onReceive()` by your code instead of by system.

Comment: Within `onClick()` and instead of sending a broadcast.